# js variable definition for if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

trying to teach myself js.

I have an ajax request I am running that returns data which includes some text and one number. The number is from a radio button list in a form and I'm trying to devise a scheme to handle the value so that:

text to be written in  is determined by the following:
if the number is 3, then it writes "not published" otherwise it writes "published"

text that to be written in  is determined by the following:
if the number is 0, it writes "in listings"
if the number is 1, it writes "in recent transactions"
if the number is 2, it writes "in listings and recent transactions"

The following is my script and it always prints "not published" and always prints "in listings and transactions" regardless of the value that's coming back to the page from my php script. the value is correct and I have these if statements working in php on another page but I need is in JS here.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "add-list.php",
            data: formData,
             success: function(response) {
                      if (response.success) {
                          $("#modal1").modal('hide');
                        $("#add_frame").show();
                        $(".azoning").html(response.zoninga);
                        var transdec = response.transactiona;
                        if (transdec=3) {$(".atrans").html("NOT PUBLISHED");} else {$(".atransaction").html("PUBLISHED");}                          
                        if (transdec=0) {$(".atransaction").html("in LISTINGS.");} 
                        if (transdec=1) {$(".atransaction").html("in RECENT TRANSACTIONS");}
                        if (transdec=2) {$(".atransaction").html("in LISTINGS AND RECENT TRANSACTIONS");}

                        }
                      else {
                          console.log("An error has ocurred: sentence: " + response.sentence + "error: " + response.error);
                      }
                  },
                                contentType: false, 
            processData: false,
                  error: function() {
                      alert("An Error has ocurred contacting the server. Please contact your system administrator");
                  }
              });
```

what's wrong with my js coding in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using assignment operators `=` instead of equality comparison operators `==` or `===`.

This:

```
   if (transdec=3) {$(".atrans").html("NOT PUBLISHED");} else {$(".atransaction").html("PUBLISHED");}
```

sets the value of "transdec" to 3, and then checks to see whether that value is "truthy".  It's non-zero, so in effect that code is like

```
   transdec = 3;
   if (true) {$(".atrans").html("NOT PUBLISHED");} else {$(".atransaction").html("PUBLISHED");}
```

Comment: thats in php only i though!??????? ok testing

Comment: @Rhillz no, in JavaScript you test for one thing being equal to another with either `==` (which will do some type coercion) or `===` (which won't).

Comment: god man you def get the award for the fastest answer on here, I didn't even finish editing a spelling error on my question

Comment: @Rhillz ha ha - well certain kinds of errors just stick out when I look at a block of code I guess

Comment: I'll accept the answer in 11 min :) your too fast for your own good

Answer (score 1):

`=` is only setting the value you need `==`

```
if (transdec==3) {$(".atrans").html("NOT PUBLISHED");} else {$(".atransaction").html("PUBLISHED");}                          
if (transdec==0) {$(".atransaction").html("in LISTINGS.");} 
if (transdec==1) {$(".atransaction").html("in RECENT TRANSACTIONS");}
if (transdec==2)....
```